What is the difference between the three sentences?

Exhausted by the work,Jane got a cup of coffee and sat down.
Jane,exhausted by the work,got a cup of coffee and sat down.
Jane got a cup of coffee and sat down, exhausted by the work.

What is the diffence between the three sentences above in meaning?

I would say the three sentences you provided all convey a similar basic idea, but they differ slightly in emphasis due to the placement of the phrase "exhausted by the work."

"Exhausted by the work, Jane got a cup of coffee and sat down."

Emphasis: This sentence emphasises Jane's exhaustion right from the start. The exhaustion is presented as the primary reason for her actions. The cause (exhaustion) is highlighted before mentioning what she does as a result (getting coffee and sitting down). The sentence flows from cause to effect.


"Jane, exhausted by the work, got a cup of coffee and sat down."

Emphasis: Here, the sentence emphasizes Jane’s identity first, then adds the detail of her exhaustion as additional information. The sentence focuses on Jane as the subject, with the exhaustion being a notable detail but not the primary focus.


"Jane got a cup of coffee and sat down, exhausted by the work."

Emphasis: In this sentence, the emphasis is on the actions (getting coffee and sitting down), with the exhaustion coming in as a final detail that explains why she did these things. The exhaustion is more of an afterthought, providing context for her actions. The sentence flows from action to cause, with the cause being secondary.



Summary

The first sentence emphasizes the cause (exhaustion) as the primary motivator for Jane’s actions.
The second sentence emphasises Jane, with the exhaustion as additional descriptive detail.
The third sentence emphasizes the actions Jane takes, with the exhaustion as a final, explanatory detail.

Each sentence is grammatically correct, but the placement of "exhausted by the work" subtly shifts the focus and flow of the sentence.

+1  But Jane got a cup of coffee and, exhausted by the work, sat down would suggest that she found getting the coffee rather tiring work.  :-)
